# Has the United States ever had a travel ban similar to the current one?

Tags: united-states

I know Japanese Americans were [not allowed to come back to America](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_Japanese_Americans) during World War II.  I also know we happily welcomed refugees from Germany, Vietnam, Korea, and the middle east in the past, even while in some sort conflict located in those areas.

Unfortunately, current search results are flooded with news of the most recent related executive order.

Has America ever done anything similar to Donald Trump's recent temporary immigration/travel ban?

Comment: Pro tip: when you google for stuff there is a search tools button. Click it and you can specify a time range for your results. Its very useful for when your results are being flooded by recent events you want to ignore

Answer (score -2):

You basically answered your own question, with regard to the Japanese Americans (and Japanese aliens).

Obama's suspended immigration from certain countries ( check out what those countries are, :) and you will see the similarity of that suspension vs the Trump suspension, and the lack of any uproar then vs now) for 6 months.

Not a thing from anyone in retraction to the Obama's suspension.

Comment: This answer would be better with more citations and a more neutral tone.

Comment: @dannyf Travel ban is not the same as being at war with another country (which was the case after Pearl Harbor).  There was no official ban.  In regards to the Obama administration, my understanding is that they blocked the Visa waiver program for certain countries, and instead slowed the process, according to this NPR report.  http://www.npr.org/2017/01/30/512487565/obama-criticizes-trumps-immigration-ban-heartened-by-protests

Comment: There will always be circumstances differences from one suspension to another. You have to look at the big picture here and see thee similarity. Btw, I forgotten about the Carter revocation of Iranian visas.

Comment: Obama did not suspend immigration from any country.  The 2011 suspension applied to refugees only, from one country only.